How to use Fourier analysis for a daily sound?
Consider I want to set up a device to record any sound near my resident. It will be, of course, record all sounds, including humans sound, birds, cats, dogs, cars, motors, building constructions, wind blows, humans activities, and many more. All those sounds will be recorded. Some of the sounds will be overlapped or overridden, some others probably will be clearer compared to another while some others will be so weak and not clear. Some will be very strong as they come just from vicinity while some other will be very weak as come from a distance. All blended as people talk in a crowded. When and how those sounds come we may say are random, in an uncertain time. For this case, I am not sure that I will have Fourier series there. Maybe just random sounds/signals.
Before I wrote this question, I have watched several video on YouTube to find what is it the Fourier series, Fourier transform, and Fourier analysis. One of the explanation I watched is the video in this link. But one she said in her explanation, "to proceed Fourier analysis, we must know the input signal, the f(t)". Indeed I will know, I will have, but not mathematically, maybe just a random signal. So my question is, how to use that Fourier analysis to such random signals that I don't know its mathematical equation? How can I use it so it will help me in signal/sound processing, especially when two or more sounds overlap or one override by another so I can separate them and proceed for further? My hope, if they already separated, I then can amplify to with normal amplification.

From the current question it doesn't seem clear what the end result of Fourier analysis is intended to be. E.g. is there a specific sound you want to be able to detect the presence of?

As in my very last sentence, I said, "My hope, if they already separated, I then can amplify with normal amplification." Do I have specific sound? No, I don't.

You can always do a Fourier analysis to any signal. The problem indeed is how you will utilize Fourier analysis, or anything else for that matter, to end up achieving what you want to achieve which is unknown. A separate issue is that are you legally allowed to record audio and  eavesdrop what other people are conversating with each other or in a phone call. You might end up illegally hearing secrets and for example making money on stock market based on what you hear.

@AirCraftLover There is a Fourier Transform and to use it you need the input description in math form. But there is also the Discrete Fourier Transform. It can operate on sampled data. There are a variety of fast methods and also methods that don't specifically require a fixed sample rate (much less commonly.) You do not have to have a math expression. You can just have a sequence of discrete data samples, or a 2d spread out, or 3d, etc. And complex or real data. There are other techniques to also apply for identifying signals or signal echo delays. So a broad array of tools to learn about.

@Justme, I actually don't have any bad intention. I just felt tired to follow the explanation in Youtube, all the examples are the easy cases, while in the real situation, we may receive signal from so many sources, different time different amplitude, and probably different frequency even though they are still in audible range. Processing audio signals could be more difficult than to proceed RF signal as the audio signals are not modulated and could be from anything, while in another hand, radio signal come from a more definitive sources and more following certain pattern.

@periblepsis, I quote yours, "*There is a Fourier Transform and to use it you need the input description in math form." As I mentioned, "Indeed I will know (the input signal), I will have, but not mathematically, maybe just a random signal." If I know the mathematical form, their equation, I will not post this question anymore.

@AirCraftLover I'm just saying you do NOT need to know the mathematical form. You can just collect ADC data. From what I read, it sounds like what you would like to explore has already been done so many times by so many people for so many years now. Nothing new.

@periblepsis, sorry for my mistake. Let me dig it deeper. Just incase you may help me, probably you have video that can help how to deal with such problem. Maybe a lecture or tutorial in Youtube. What I don't like from all the explanation in Youtube, the example case always too easy, the input signals are mostly the easy things, while in real condition could be so complicated, the sound comes from many sources and any form. Human voice are easier than sound of such as construction hammers, engines, cars, trains, etc.

@AirCraftLover There are a number of related and/or overlapping disciplines involved. You seem focused on Fourier. But there is a lot more to know about before you can have the ability to choose the right tools and apply them together in the right ways. From what I read in your question, I think you need more than Fourier knowledge. So it's just too much for me to suggest anything. Stuff I like you may not. Etc. And there's much to gather up. You'll have to plan on a bit of a schedule ahead, I think.

"I think you need more than Fourier knowledge." What else I need to know? I have followed even lectures of many lecturers, I have the solid understanding regarding what they taught. The problem is, the example they provided mostly just a simple thing. Just like in the link I attached, she just mentioned high pitch over a piano sound. Of course, we may filter it easily. Maybe Fourier analysis not so required there, just need filter.

You can apply the Fourier transform to any signal.  You don't need to know the content of the signal beforehand.
Pretty much any signal can be decomposed into frequencies and amplitudes by the Fourier transformation.
What you do have to know is the sampling rate at which the signal was digitized.  That is to say, you need to know how many evenly spaced samples per second were made.  The sampling rate tells you (among other things) the maximum frequency that can be represented in the Fourier transform. Together with the number of samples you use in the transform, it also tells you what frequency each "bin" in the transformation result represents.
Mathematical discussions of the Fourier transform (such as on the Wikipedia Fourier transform page) often start with a known function to which the transform is applied.  This is, however, just to illustrate how the transform works.  You know the input signal so that you know what to expect from the transform. You can the verify the output by comparing it to the known input.
Once you know what the transform does, you can apply it to any signal and trust that what it shows you is a fair representation of the input signal.
As an example, here's a look at a Fourier transformation of me whistling at my Android phone:

It shows a peak at 1523Hz.  I certainly had no idea what it would look like, but the Fourier transformation easily found the content.
As a further example, here's what the frequency content of my voice looks like when I say "aaaaaaaa".

There's a bunch of peaks to the left, representing the primary tone of my voice along with several harmonics.
That's the useful thing about the Fourier transform.  It decomposes an existing signal to show you what is in it - without you having to tell it what to expect.

"Mathematical discussions of the Fourier transform (such as on the Wikipedia Fourier transform page) often start with a known function to which the transform is applied." As I mentioned, I don't have mathematical equation for that signal. As you probably may guess, sound on engines, cars, motors, building constructions, are almost not following pattern. Cats and dogs' sound probably are more simple. Even voice of people talking in a crowded also are not simple. I can not model them mathematically. About I don't have mathematical equation, I have mentioned it in my post as I anticipated.

The mathematical discussions use a known function as an example. You do not need a known function to apply the Fourier transform.

From the case I described in my post, there are many sounds with many types which come in form, time, amplitude, and maybe frequency (like sound of pile hammer). Some they overlap over another, or the stronger sounds override the weaker. So, how could I separate them?
